# SQL Lite Exception

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have generated my model from `SQLLite` in my Application , but when i try to call `DBContext` Call it's throwing an exception.

> An exception of type `System.IO.FileLoadException` occurred in
>   `mscorlib.dll` but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.93.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Please help me.

Comment: What is your application Asp.Net, Windows Forms, WP8?

Comment: 3 Layers, Front end is (MVC)Asp.net, Data get from (Web API) middle end, Web API connected to the (Class Library) where the SQL Lite Connected to the Code First.

Comment: @Joby Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93879/hresult-0x80131040-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-t?

Answer (score 0):

Control your WebApi and Asp.Net MVC projects output bin directories to see that if they actually have System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll.

Most probably they do not have this dll and you need to set [Copy Local](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx) property for this dll.

Comment: I added this dll in all my project, but still it showing same error.

Comment: Sharing my test application https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3605vb89exzLW5DdnVEaTR5bWM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue in the past. The issue in my case was that
I was adding the same dll from file system and then had a nuget package as well as for the same component.

In your case I can see you have a nuget package of different version "System.Data.SQLite.EF6.1.0.97.0". I would do the below
a. Remove all the references (static dlls if there are any).
b. Add the references from the nuget package.

BTW, the sln file you sent doesn't have csproj (so can't open the proj files).

Answer (score 0):

Before going into solution let me **explain** to you about the errors that you are facing right now :

`System.IO.FileLoadException` :

> The exception that is thrown when a managed assembly is found but
> cannot be loaded.

**[mscorlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061977/what-does-mscorlib-stand-for) :**

> Microsoft Core Library, ie they are at the heart of everything

**[Ref-Def-Mismatch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/03/25/95826.aspx)**:

This exception is thrown when there is an assembly that does not match what you are looking for. A very common **mismatch** is version number,which is the case **here**.

You should [clean up the config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757843/system-data-sqlite-1-0-91-0-and-ef6-0-2/28761918#28761918) and provide the necessary Entity Framework Providers .

More reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215026/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)