# Why is VBA's VarType function saying this COM object is a string? (Object is instance of COM version of .NET's System.Object class.) Is it a bug?

Tags: .net, excel, vba, com, .net-4.0

### Question summary

When I use VBA's [`VarType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function)  function, passing it an instance of the `Object` class available in a [mscorlib.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061977/what-does-mscorlib-stand-for) library reference (a [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/) library reference), the value returned is `8`.

According to VBA documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function), this means the object is a string. This seems ridiculous.

My question is why is the [`VarType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) function returning a string-type value for instances of this `Object` class from the .NET-library VBA reference? Is it a bug?

### Background information

I suspect that the fact that VBA's `VarType` function is saying a certain COM object is a string, may be why I'm having problems using the [`DispCallFunc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-dispcallfunc) function on certain methods of certain COM objects. The COM objects are COM versions of .NET objects, made available through the .NET framework.

I'm using the mscorlib.dll VBA reference to get early-binding functionality for these objects. The reference refers to version 4.0.30319 of the .NET framework. On my computer, the type library for the reference is stored at:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb.

It is looking like when the object method specifies that an argument or return value be of type [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object), `DispCallFunc` fails to work for me. Anyway, that is a separate problem that is circumstantial to the problem this question is dedicated to.

---

At the time of writing, I'm running the latest version of Excel (Version 1903, Build 11425.20202). My operating system is Windows 8.1.

---

When I use the `VarType` function with instances of other classes from the mscorlib.dll library, I sometimes get return values of `9` & `13` (`VbVarType.vbObject` & `VbVarType.vbDataObject` constants) which seems correct.

I researched on the internet to see whether anyone else had encountered the problem but couldn't find anything.

### Code that can be used to reproduce problem

```
Dim o As mscorlib.Object
Set o = New mscorlib.Object
Debug.Print "TypeName(o) = " & TypeName(o) ' TypeName function seems to work correctly.
Debug.Print "o.Equals(o) = " & o.Equals(o) ' System.Object.Equals method is working.

Debug.Print "VarType(CVar(o)) = " & VarType(CVar(o)) ' IMPORTANT LINE
' VBA VarType function says o is string (type 8) but it isn't?!

Debug.Print "VbVarType.vbString = " & VbVarType.vbString
```

I expected `VarType(CVar(o))` to return `9`, `13` or some other appropriate integer. Instead, it returned `8` which does not seem appropriate at all (`8` represents strings.)

Comment: Perhaps the object has a default property, in which case `VarType` (as per the docs) returns the type of that property.

Comment: Does `Debug.Print o` output anything or blow up?

Comment: Yes Rory, I believe the answer has to do with the type of the default property being returned. I should have read the VarType documentation more thoroughly - didn't expect such functionality. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the typeLib `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb` with [OleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/using-oleview) for example, and navigate to the `_Object` interface (not the first _Object one, the dispinterface, but the second one) you'll see this:

[image]

So, the .NET method `Object.ToString()` is declared to COM/Automation clients as

```
[id(00000000), propget, custom(54FC8F55-38DE-4703-9C4E-250351302B1C, 1)]
HRESULT ToString([out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);
```

Which means it's seen to COM clients that understand this "syntactic sugar" (VB/VBA/VBScript/JScript/.NET, etc.) as a *Property* (propget + out + retval) named `ToString` that returns a *String* (BSTR).

Now, `id(0)` means it's the *default property*, because 0 represents [DISPID_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/cb9d0131-c6bd-463d-9c40-7264856a10c5), a special well-known id.

And lastly, VB/VBA [VarType's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) states this:

> If an object has a default property, VarType(object) returns the type
>   of the object's default property.

(which I always found a pretty strange design decision...)

Comment: how does one actually get to the view you show in the image please? Is a download required?

Comment: @QHarr - OleView.exe is available with Windows SDK, in a path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86 fore example. If you have Visual Studio, you should have it as well.

Comment: This answer seems to be spot on the correct answer. Thank you so much for this. I should have read the VarType documentation properly - didn't expect such behaviour. I learnt of the function from someone else's code who seems to have more or less made the same mistake as me.

I've learnt so much from these Stack Overflow answers. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkFernandes feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the hollow green checkmark under the up/down voting buttons near the top of the post. IMO the explanation doesn't get any more canonical that this.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I've created a pull request on GitHub for the VarType documentation, to make it more clear in the documentation that VarType has this 'unusual' behaviour. See 'https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/pull/956' for the request.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the duplicate (little search didn't retrieve this question). Upvoted. Sounds like it's not possible out of the box to write a function wich returns either a COM visible Assembly object or a string and differentiate them upwards (I'm trying to set an efficient way to check fail creation and get the error message).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,40) for `object.cs`, I'm not seeing any `[DispId]` attributes, but assuming the first member gets marshaled with `[DispId(0)]`, that would make the `ToString` method the COM type's *default member*.

That's the only explanation I have for `Debug.Print o` outputting `System.Object`, rather than blowing up with error 438 as it normally would without a default member.

So the problem isn't so much with .NET/COM interop, rather it's about dealing with getting metadata out of an object that has a default member: you would have the exact same problem with any COM object that has a `String` default member:

```
?VarType(Application), VarType(Application.Name)
 8             8
```

I can't think of a way off the top of my head to make `VarType` work with these. On the other hand, a `TypeOf...Is` check works fine:

```
?TypeOf Application Is Object
True
```

Hence:

```
Debug.Print TypeOf o Is Object ' True
```

Comment: This answer appears to be more or less correct. Thank you so much for this. I should have read the VarType documentation properly - didn't expect such function behaviour. I learnt of the function from someone else's code who seems to have more or less made the same mistake as me.

I've learnt so much from these Stack Overflow answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a part of the problem is that VBA evaluates expressions in certain cases (maybe someone can add more information on when/why this happens). So, when you make the call to `VarType(o)`, the `o` variable is actually being converted to a string representation, and the type is taken.

As an example, if you write `Debug.Print o`, the output will be `System.Object`. If you write `Debug.Print x` on a different, concrete object, the system will possibly throw an error.

Try the following syntax:

```
Debug.Print VarType(o.GetType)
```

In my case, that returns the value 13.

Comment: `Object.GetType()` returns a `Type`, which is an `Object` indeed - but that's not the type of `o`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon This makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I thought that the ToString method probably had something to do with it, but missed reading the VarType documentation where it says that the type of the default property is returned - didn't expect such behaviour. Thanks for looking into this. Hopefully, this Stack Overflow question will help others.