# Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using a code to update a file with a loop running through multiple sheets. Up until now, the code ran smoothly. On today's run, I encountered "run-time error '-2147319767 (80028029)' Automation error, Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type."

The error occurs on the line `Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("C7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` and presents itself on the 6th iteration of the loop.

I used `On Error Resume Next` as a temporary measure to complete the run as it was imperative to have it done at that time.

Upon completion, 3 of the iterations had failed (sixth, seventh and tenth). The three had no correlation to one another (i.e. different copy sources, values, etc) but had other iterations with the exact same copy source/values which completed successfully.

Running another copy command at a later time onto these sheets resulted in the same error. I eventually had to delete and recreate the sheet to resolve the error.

```
' Uploads file update

fpath = Workbooks("TEG Rates.xlsm").Worksheets("Link List").Range("E3").Value

Workbooks.Open fpath & "Upload.xlsm"

For branchNo = 21 To 37

    branchName = Workbooks("TEG Rates.xlsm").Worksheets("Link List").Range("A" & branchNo).Value
    branchGroup = Workbooks("TEG Rates.xlsm").Worksheets("Link List").Range("B" & branchNo).Value

    ' Copy/Paste Buy & Sell

    Workbooks("TEG Rates.xlsm").Worksheets(branchGroup).Range("D7:G111").Copy
    Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("C7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    For no = 7 To 10

        Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("D" & no).Value = "=ROUND(100/C" & no & ",6)"

    Next no

    Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("D14").Value = "=ROUND(100/C14,6)"
    Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("D15").Value = "=ROUND(10000/C15,4)"

    Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("D16").Value = "=ROUND(100/C16,6)"
    Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("D19").Value = "=ROUND(100/C19,6)"

Next branchNo

Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

While currently I am able to operate this code, my concern is that my team will encounter this whilst I'm away. What could have caused this/what can I do to prevent this from occurring? I'd be willing to provide the files if required.

Comment: Attempted recording a macro to identify if it is an issue with a cell or range, appears to be an issue with selecting the sheet.

Comment: It could be that branchname contains some **special character** or is not in text format for those specific iterations. So excel is not able to open that worksheet.

Comment: Not the case, this has been running perfectly for the past three weeks. The branchnames were "Victoria Street","Ludgate Hill" & "London Bridge" without the quotation marks. As mentioned, deleting the sheet and recreating it in the same name (or using an older file from my backups) works.

Answer (score 76):

My friend and I had the same issue. I enabled the "AccessibilitycplAdmin 1.0 type admin" under Tools > References (within the VBA editor), that fixed the issue in both computers

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks Ben!

Comment: This worked for me!  I'm really curious why this happens, and why this solution works.

Comment: MikeS's comment as edit in answer: "*I had the same issue. I enabled the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" under Tools > References (within the VBA editor), that fixed the issue !!*"

Comment: Hello! Same problem, solution worked. I'd really love some insight on what this is and why it fixes this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks  - why did "this break" if nothing changed and it worked a day before... ??  lekka windows!

Comment: It works for me too, Thank you. Also, for those looking for supporting info on how this works, scroll to @pgSystemTester's answer.

Answer (score 14):

### Explanation of Top Answer

The top answer's [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698445/11732320) of adding a VBA library reference works because it forces the file to recompile its VBA libraries, effectively reestablishing the proper order to run macros against various objects in the application.

**Note:**

- It does not matter what VBA library reference you check -- there's nothing special about the accessibility libraries.
- You don't have to keep the library enabled, in fact, it would be best to remove the library after confirming the issue is resolved. Keeping it enabled only adds complexity to the file's VBA library which was ultimately the root cause of this issue in the first place.
- I almost always lose my [double click event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dblclick-event) when this happens, which serves as a good indicator (obviously with `Application.Events=True`)

### Other Information

#### VBA Error You're Likely Seeing:

[image: VBA ERROR]

#### What it *PROBABLY* Means

While this isn't a specific error, the likely cause is that Excel is trying to run a procedure out of order, effectively not knowing what objects are being used that are normally established. As an example, your macro might be running a procedure referencing a standard object such as `Sheet1`, only the library has failed to establish what `Sheet1` is yet.

#### Actions I've Noticed That Seem Likely To Trigger Issue

- DEBUGGING
- Using excessive [event macros](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/)
- Using Excel/VBA Add ons

  - [MZ Tools](https://www.mztools.com/) in particular seems to increase the likelihood of trigging this, though I would still recommend it as a tool
- Adding other vba libraries (i.e. adobe, SAP, etc).

Comment: Thanks for this supporting info for the top answer.

Comment: @ChaosPH thank you. It's been getting a lot of upvotes lately, so I'm happy to know that it's well-received.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue with a macro today. 

Noticed that the error popped up when selecting a sheet using `Sheets(sheet_name_var).Select`.

A workaround that I've found is:

- Make a copy of the sheet the macro was having problems with,

- Delete the original sheet,

- Rename the copy to the original name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that only works if you do not have formula references to that sheet

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same error caused by an issue that was potentially related, and it was helpful to create a worksheet object rather than referencing a sheet within a workbook all in one step.  So, instead of:

```
Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets(branchName).Range("C7").PasteSpecial
```

You could instead try:

```
Dim xlWB as Excel.Workbook 
Dim xlWS as Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRange as Excel.Range
Set xlWB = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm")
Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(branchname)
Set xlRange = xlWS.Range("C7")
xlRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Sometimes it's beneficial to break up the steps, even though it is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found to solve it was:

- Change the property "Load To" for all query results in the damaged Sheet to "Only Create Connection".
- Make a copy of the Sheet
- Delete the damaged Sheet
- Rename the just created Sheet to the name of the damaged one
- Change all the query results to the new Sheet in the same original location

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue, I have several similar excel files, all with the same code. The code ran in all excels but one, with the same error:

```
"run-time error '-2147319767 (80028029)' Automation error, Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type."
```

I was able to solve the problem by saving the corrupt excel as .xlsx instead of .xlsm, closing all excel applications, reopen the .xlsx, add the code and save as .xlsm. Now it is working...

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this a number of times. My simplest solution: If I know which sheet is causing the problem, I goto vba, rename the sheet (name and codename) with F4. Run the code. If I get no errors I rename it back.
If it is not a specific sheet, I try this with each sheet, one at a time.
Has worked every time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same thing happened to me. But with a little bit more serious consequences as my dashboard was already in production.
It was really shocking as code as running smoothly just 5 mins earlier.

Here's the changes that I made -

1. Conditional formatting
2. Pivot table updates - major formatting updates

I believe some weird combination of conditional formatting over pivot table might have caused this issue.

**One peculiar symptom associated with this corrupted workbook/sheet as that I was unable to see any macro in the dialogue while I was trying to assign a macro to the button.
The dialogue box was empty ! not listing any macros from any module/form/worksheet.**

Tried -

1. Removing pivot table
2. Resetting formatting
3. Removing conditional formatting
4. Restarting excel
5. Restarting system

None of the above worked !

Next solution, as suggested by Horacio, is to duplicate and delete the corrupted sheet.
This immediately solved the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30880882)

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem - same error. The sheet is the results of a query "Load To" table. Followed the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/users/13737858/horacio-cano. Changed "Load to" from table to Connection only; deleted the sheet; changed "Load to" to new table; refreshed query. Macro runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime in Tools>References selecting "Ok" and then re-adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

(Not the exactly the same situation as posted by the OP, but the same error message:)

I got the same error message while trying to delete an ActiveX element in a UserForm.

Turns out that I still had (another) user form open as a modal window in the Excel app (which was in the background because I was trying to edit it the Visual Basic Editor).

Simply closing the user form solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but my 2 cents on the matter (a comment could not fit it :))

I found that the underlaying error comes from .NET:

```
Exception Source:      mscorlib
Exception Type:        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Exception Message:     Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028029 (TYPE_E_INVALIDSTATE))
Exception Target Site: InvokeDispMethod
```

With that, I found that this page:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/live-code-analysis-causes-compiler-errors-in-code/599442

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : A reference to the component 'MyProjectReference' already exists in the project.
at VSLangProj.References.AddProject(Project pProject)
```

So it appears the error is linked to some cached file(s) used internally and language stuff.

Now if you look here : [What does 'Cor' stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123345/what-does-cor-stand-for)

> MSCorLib.dll officially became the acronym for Multilanguage Standard
> Common Object Runtime Library.

If you finally add in the mix that I was manupulating files in Excel while changing the UI Language in settings just before I got a corrupted file with the same error that the OP mentions, I would guess the error definitely has some thing to do it!...

Answer (score 0):

In my version of the error discussed here, a worksheet is successfully passed to two subroutines before it disappears on a Rows.Count call in the next line throwing the error at that point. Since the sheet existed at the start of the sub I created a copy of the same under another name `Set WsNew = WsOld`and then referred to it by the new name instead of the old. That resolved the problem.

I believe that the error is caused by Excel's slow response either to changing protection status or the setting of Application.Calculation or both, not any inherent corruption of the worksheet or missing reference.

In Xenox Dissanyake's case, I believe the error is probably caused by assigning a Formula to the cells' Value property butthe fact that the error does not occur on every iteration of the loop may indicate that this, too, is a speed problem.

However, the structure of Xenox's code makes it difficult to determine whether it is a workbook or a worksheet that disappears, as happens in my case, or to apply the same remedy. In the code suggested below, the relevant sheets are already reset on each iteration and the formula is not assigned to the cells' Value property. Therefore it seems unlikely to cause the problem that gave rise to Xenox's question.

```
Dim WbRates         As Workbook
Dim WbUpload        As Workbook
Dim WsList          As Worksheet
Dim WsGroup         As Worksheet
Dim WsBranch        As Worksheet
Dim fpath           As String
Dim branchName      As String
Dim branchGroup     As String
Dim branchNo        As Integer
Dim No              As Integer

Set WbRates = Workbooks("TEG Rates.xlsm")
Set WsList = WbRates.Worksheets("Link List")
fpath = WsList.Range("E3").Value

Set WbUpload = Workbooks.Open(fpath & "Upload.xlsm")

For branchNo = 21 To 37
    With WsList
        branchName = .Cells(branchNo, "A").Value
        branchGroup = .Cells(branchNo, "B").Value
    End With
    Set WsGroup = WbRates.Worksheets(branchGroup)
    Set WsBranch = WbUpload.Worksheets(branchName)

    ' Copy/Paste Buy & Sell

    WsGroup.Range("D7:G111").Copy
    WsBranch.Range("C7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    For No = 7 To 10
        WsBranch.Range("D" & No).Formula = "=ROUND(100/C" & No & ",6)"
    Next No
Next branchNo

Application.CutCopyMode = False
WbUpload.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

The code is untested and I apologize for any errors it may contain. The intention is to demonstrate the structure, not to provide a ready-to-use solution.