# invalid forward reference or reference to uncompiled type

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Macro that has been working for months without any issue.
It selects another tab, where it looks at data coming from a MySQL database.

Suddenly today I get : **invalid forward reference or reference to uncompiled type**

This on the line of code

```
Do While Worksheets("Forecast").Cells(i, 2) <> ""
```

I have a couple of Macros, doing this for other worksheets as well.
So it seems the VBA code is not able to refer to another sheet in the same workbook.

What changed?

The worksheets exitst, and contains data.

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272229/invalid-forward-reference-or-reference-to-uncompiled-type)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272229/invalid-forward-reference-or-reference-to-uncompiled-type)

Answer (score 0):

**Do While Worksheets("Forecast").Cells(i, 2) <> ""**

Changing code in the one below, works ?!

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Sheets("Orders")

Do While sheet.Cells(i, 2) <> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to declare an object:

```vb
Do While Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Forecast").Cells(i, 2) <> ""
```