# VBA - cannot select a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which I have been using for a while when suddenly it doesn't work properly.
Sheet selection causes error:

`Sheets("sheet_name").Select`

[image: VBA error]

It has worked for a long time, the other strange things are:

1. I cannot copy the sheet.
2. When I try to save the file without any changes I get another error:
   [image: VBA saving error]

Saving attempt fails too.

How can I fix this? I tried making a new copy of the sheets and file, but it doesn't help.
Do I need to create this file from scratch?

Comment: I've been encountering this same issue a couple of times lately, what I do is revert it back to a previous save-state. I'd prefer a better way to prevent this if possible but for now that's my advice. Also, you [don't need to use Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: You need to install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  Rubberduck has the ability to export the current project in one click.  It can also install a whole project using the add files option in the code explorer.  This make recreating a workbook relatively simple.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272229/invalid-forward-reference-or-reference-to-uncompiled-type

Comment: @Notus_Panda, thank you for the link, now I see I should rewrite some code :)

Comment: @freelow, this addin is interesting, I have never heard about it. Thank you!

Comment: @Dominique, unfortunately I have this option enabled and it doesn't work anyway :(

Comment: Did you read this explanation regarding why the answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665879/16578424 - you have to add any reference, but add one new to get the project recompiled.