# There is Automation error (Error 440) with easy code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with vba and run vba everyday.
1<sup>st</sup> sheet : Data
2<sup>nd</sup> sheet : Keyin

my vba code is:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
'
' Button2_Click Macro
'
    Sheets("Keyin").Select

'
End Sub
```

One day when the button2 was clicked. Excel show dialog box as attached

What happen with my Excel.

[image: This is all problem and codes.]

I use this file everyday.
The problem occurred on Jan 1<sup>st</sup> and has persisted until today.

Virus was checked.
Mulware was checked also.

Comment: Any code in the worksheet being selected?

Comment: Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272229/invalid-forward-reference-or-reference-to-uncompiled-type

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. with VBA there is almost never a need to select a sheet to perform operations on it, it is better to reference the sheet, e.g.:

With Sheets("Keyin")

```
 .Range("A1").Copy
```

...
End With

2. you can try

Sheets("Keyin").Activate

3. you can access the sheet via the CodeName (The one that appears in the project window in VBA), e.g.

Sheet1.Activate

Comment: Thanks so much.

But don't know why the current code can run normally. No need to edit anything.