# Getting Runtime Error '424" Object Required for code that is already in my WORD Template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've made several related templates in WORD using VBA.  I needed to add a feature to all of them so I did the changes to the coding and UserForm1 to effect the needed upgrades.  It worked fine in that template.  I then copied/pasted the new code and UserForm1 elements to the other templates.  It worked fine on several templates but not in others.

In the problematic templates I got a "Runtime Error '424' Object Required".  The Debugger then indicated there was an issue with the following code (UserForm1.Show was highlighted):

```vb
   Sub Document_New()
      UserForm1.Show

   End Sub
```

This is the same code contained in the templates that work fine.

I tried deleting/replacing this code which did not fix the problem.

I verified "UserForm1" is the name of the User Forms in all the templates.

Looking for suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might have an issue of needing to recompile your vba. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665879/11732320)

Comment: Probably the error occurs in the code-behind of the userform. In the VBA editor, goto  Tools->Options. On the General Tab, select "Break in Class Module" and retry. The VBA editor now should display the statement causing the issue. If this is the case: Edit the question and add the code. Mention the line where the error occurs.

Comment: FunThomas, I ended up deleting and retyping the code that had been cut/pasted.  That fixed the problem.  I'm wondering if there was some "hidden" code that was a part of what I originally cut/pasted.  Is that a thing in VBA? I'm very new at this.  Anyway, I will save your suggestion and use it if I run into a similar situation in the future.  Thanks!