# Why am I suddently getting a VBA Automation Error in code that has been thoroughly tested?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

The following code has never given an error until now

```
Sheets("Template").Visible = True
```

The error is:

[image]

I was able to eliminate the error by writing

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
set sh = Sheets("Template")
sh.Visible = True
```

This is the Office 365 version of Excel. Since Office apps are updated automatically, could an automatic update by Microsoft have caused this? There was an Excel update on Feb 13.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on Excel365.

Comment: You just had that one line of code?  I think we're missing a lot of context there.

Comment: Suggestion: Try an "Online Repair" of Office 365. While it is very unlikely, an automatic update definitely can break Excel. I had it happen to me about 6 months ago. A worksheet that functioned for 3 years without fault or modification suddenly had a very specific line of VBA fail. Every PC that was internet connected failed too, but not the unconnected ones. I managed a workaround in the meantime, and a few weeks later it "microraculously" fixed itself.

Comment: Excucution halted at the line of code in the first snippet. I got the same error if I typed Sheets("Template").Name in the Immediate window.  But if I use the codename,  Sheet4.Name, it outputs "Template" and does not cause an error.

Comment: Have you had a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272229/invalid-forward-reference-or-reference-to-uncompiled-type/76665879#76665879? The accepted answer (and the explanation by user *pgSystemTester*) suggest you need to add any reference to force VBA to do a complete recompile. After that, you can remove the reference again.